# Sorting columns in table parses Underscores in field names and breaks sorting

Tags: jhipster

I have some entities, where the property and field name has an underscore in it, like "display_name". I am able to see it in the table, the column and all. However, when I click on the sorting button in the header for that column in the UI page for that entity, it throws an exception that the property "display" does not exist. Of course, it doesn't it is "display_name"

I think Spring's PropertyPath class is splitting that string with the underscore.

How can I get the UI column sort to work for this column?

Comment: There was a recent issue for this on the Spring Data JIRA that was closed with "working as designed": https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-816

Comment: Thanks Gerald, and I was able to change the property in the Java class to not have an underscore. Oliver is always correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeraldHumphries posted in the commonts above...

There was a recent issue for this on the Spring Data JIRA that was closed with "working as designed": jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-816

That was exactly what I needed and was able to just change the underscored fields in the json to camel case and it all still worked with the actual db fields still having underscores.